# Parsing XML error, arrayindexoutofbounds exception.

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to parse some XML to a string and I'm getting an `outofbounds` exception. I'm fairly new to android as well as trying to get text from a website, namely the CTA Bus Tracker API . One block of the `XML` looks like this:

```
    <route>
       <rt>1</rt>
       <rtnm>Bronzeville/Union Station</rtnm>
    </route>
```

This is my method:

```
class loadRoutes extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {
    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            URL routesURL = new URL(strings[0]);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(routesURL.openStream()));
            String [] result = new String[2];
            String line;
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if(line.contains("<rt>")) {
                    int firstPos = line.indexOf("<rt>");
                    String tempNum = line.substring(firstPos);
                    tempNum = tempNum.replace("<rt>", "");
                    int lastPos = tempNum.indexOf("</rt>");
                    result[0] = tempNum.substring(0, lastPos);
                    in.readLine();
                    firstPos = line.indexOf("<rtnm>");
                    String tempName = line.substring(firstPos);
                    tempName = tempName.replace("<rtnm>", "");
                    lastPos = tempName.indexOf("</rtnm>");
                    result[1] = tempName.substring(0, lastPos);
                }
            }
            in.close();
            return result;
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The first `readline()` gets to the line with an `rt` and grabs that line, then in the if statement, `readline()` should get the next line, which should contain `rtnm`. I keep getting `indexoutofbounds` on the line `firstPos = line.indexOf("rtnm")`.

Comment: You can use Sax parser or DOM to parse xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop is already reading in the next line, so you don't need to  `in.readLine();` in the if statement. Try running it like this:

```
while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.contains("<rt>")) {
                int firstPos = line.indexOf("<rt>");
                String tempNum = line.substring(firstPos);
                tempNum = tempNum.replace("<rt>", "");
                int lastPos = tempNum.indexOf("</rt>");
                result[0] = tempNum.substring(0, lastPos);
            } else if (line.contains("<rtnm>") {
                firstPos = line.indexOf("<rtnm>");
                String tempName = line.substring(firstPos);
                tempName = tempName.replace("<rtnm>", "");
                lastPos = tempName.indexOf("</rtnm>");
                result[1] = tempName.substring(0, lastPos);
            }
        }
```

Also, it might be easier to write your own XML parser in a different class. This [XML parser android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) has an example of exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, and I'll definitely take a look at the XML parser documentation.